# Distribution profile expired of an app in the App Store

Tags: ios, provisioning

A lot of my certificates are expired today. I want to update my app that is currently in the App Store and saw that I need to create another distribution profile with the same bundle id. IS this correct?

So, for example my bundle id of the old distribution profile was "com.xxxx.1234" , now I need to create another one with the same "com.xxxx.1234" ?

Cheers and thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should only have two certificates - one for development and one for distribution. Do not confuse certificates with provisioning profiles. They are very different though the provisioning profiles depend on one of the certificates.

If in fact your certificate(s) did expire (which they do once a year), create and install your new certificate(s). Once that is in place all you need to do is edit your existing provisioning profiles to use the new certificate. Do not create any new provisioning profiles, just update what you have.

Once all of the provisioning profiles are updated, download and install the updates into Xcode. Delete the expired ones.

Now update your project to be sure it uses the updated profiles.

No where in this process should you deal with bundle ids.

Comment: OK, I have requested and downloaded my new distribution and development certificates through the keychain and uploaded to apple. And now? I installed them in the organizer but now I don't know what to do :( Also there is a temporary maintenance of the apple servers...

Comment: Also, do I need to delete the old certificates from the keychain?

Comment: You might as well. The expired certificates are of no use.